# Removable Singularity Problems at $z = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

My problem is to find the radius of convergence $R$ of the function $f(z) = \frac{z}{\sin(z)}$ around the the point $z_{0} = \pi i$. I find the singularities of $f(z)$ are $z = n \pi$ ($n$ is integer). But why $z = 0$ is a removable singularity? If considering another function $g(z) = \frac{z^{2}}{(\sin(z))^{3}}$. At $z = 0$ is a pole. Can you please explain to me how to determine the difference between these two types of singularities.?

Answer (score 1):

The point $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$ because the limit $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$ exists in $\mathbb C$. In the case of $g$, the limit also exits, but it is equal to $\infty$. Therefore, $g$ has a pole at $0$, instead of a removable singularity.

And there is no such thing as the radius of convergence of a function at a point.

Comment: I see what you are saying. But after that I think you can find the radius of convergence. For $f(z)$, $R = \pi \sqrt{2}$ and for $g(z)$ it will be $R = \pi$.

Comment: As I wrote, there is no such thing as the radius of convergence of a function at a point.  What do you meant by that?

Comment: The radius of convergence around the given point say $z_0$ is just the distance from the nearest isolated singularity to the point $z_0$. I think I may be tedious when not explaining in details. But anyway, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: In that case, $R=\pi$ in both cases: it's the distance from $\pi$ to $0$ (and from $\pi$ to $2\pi$).